# How do I use express to render geojson?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, geojson, vega-lite

I am trying to use express .render() to add geojson to a vega-lite visualization in an ejs file, but I keep receiving this error message in my browser:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/karoline/Desktop/Afleveres/index.ejs:132
    130|         "layer": [{
    131|             "data": {
 >> 132|                 "values": <%- geoVisData %>,
    133|                 "format": {
    134|                     "type": "topojson",
    135|                     "feature": "geometry"

geoVisData is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/karolineschafer/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:10:17)
    at index (/Users/karoline/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/karoline/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/karoline/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/Users/karoline/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/karoline/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/karoline/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/karoline/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/karoline/Desktop/Afleveres/server.js:13:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/karoline/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Does express not accept geojson, or am I doing something wrong?

The code in my express file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express();
const fs = require("fs");

expressApp.set("view engine", "ejs")
expressApp.set("views", __dirname)


expressApp.get('/', function(request, response){
    let visData = fs.readFileSync("visData.json", "utf-8");
     let geoVisData = fs.readFileSync("koebenhavns-storkreds.geojson");

    response.render('index', {
        visData: visData, 
        geoVisData: geoVisData
    });
})

app.use(Express.static(__dirname));

expressApp.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on port 8080')
});
```

And the code in my ejs file looks like this:

```
let mapVis = {
        "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
        "width": 1300,
        "height": 1200,
        "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
        "layer": [{
            "data": {
                "data": {"values": <%- geoVisData %>},
                "format": {
                    "type": "topojson",
                    "feature": "geometry"
                }
            },
            "projection": {
                "type": "mercator"
            },
            "mark": {
                "type": "geoshape",
                "fill": "lightgray",
                "stroke": "white"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {"values": <%- visData %>},
            "projection": {
                "type": "mercator"
            },
            "mark": "circle",
            "params": [{
                "name": "show",
                "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["hygge"]},
                "bind": "legend"
            }],
            "encoding": {
                "longitude": {
                    "field": "longitude",
                    "type": "quantitative"
                },
                "latitude": {
                    "field": "latitude",
                    "type": "quantitative"},
                "size": {
                    "value": 30
                },
                "tooltip": [
                    {"field": "name", "type": "nominal", "title": "Name"},
                    {"field": "neighborhood", "type": "nominal", "title": "Neighborhood"},
                    {"field": "accommodationType", "type": "nominal", "title": "Type"},
                    {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Price per night"}
                ],
                "color": {
                    "field": "hygge", "type": "nominal", "title": "Hygge?",
                    "scale": {"range": ["#6BB7B9", "#FF5A5F"]}
                },
                "href": {"field": "link", "type": "nominal"},
                "opacity": {
                    "condition": {"param": "show", "value": 1},
                    "value": 0.2
                }
            }
        }
        ],
        "config": {
            "font": "Avenir"
        }
    }
```

The <%- visData %> (which is a json file) works, but the <%- geoVisData %> (which is a geojson file) doesn't.

Comment: The ejs syntax of `<%- geoVisData %>` might not be proper. Can you try the `<%= geoVisData %>` or any of the following from [here](https://github.com/tj/ejs#features). Else you can simply define your `geoVisData` as a simple variable use it in  the vega-lite config.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I tried the onthers, and they don't work either. 
I also tried defining my geoVisData as a simple variable, but that causes problems as well – when I do that, the visualization does not appear and I get these error messages in the console: 
"GEThttp://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]" and
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._data is undefined"